# Find Place requests Returns Only One Result

Tags: google-places-api, google-places

I'm using the Google Places API endpoint "findplacefromtext" and tried a search similar to the example.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json?input=mongolian%20grill&inputtype=textquery&fields=photos,formatted_address,name,opening_hours,rating&locationbias=circle:2000@47.6918452,-122.2226413&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

However, when you use this it only ever returns one result.  There is a cafe near me that's called "Cream" but when you pass that as the "input" parameter it returns shops that have a category of "Ice Cream".  I thought it should only search the name of the business.... If I can't find the place by name does it search the category type as a fall back?  When I execute the same search in Google Maps it returns the same data but I get multiple results and I can see the place I am trying to retrieve 3rd on the search result list.

Is it possible to make it return more than one result?  The documentation doesn't mention anything about this.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you figure it out?

Comment: Unfortunately it seems like a limitation of that specific API endpoint...

Answer (score 8):

I believe what you need is the *Text Search request*. The *Find Place request* is meant for exact addresses.

> The Google Places API Text Search Service is a web service that
> returns information about a set of places based on a string — for
> example "pizza in New York" or "shoe stores near Ottawa" or "123 Main
> Street". The service responds with a list of places matching the text
> string and any location bias that has been set.
>
> The service is especially useful for making ambiguous address queries
> in an automated system, and non-address components of the string may
> match businesses as well as addresses. Examples of ambiguous address
> queries are incomplete addresses, poorly formatted addresses, or a
> request that includes non-address components such as business names.

Taken from https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/search#TextSearchRequests

Comment: Google seems inconsistent with textsearch everything was working good and suddenly started returning one result. When in capital letter only one result when lower case worked. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/258933675